# Error while trying to serialize a Qlik Sense app into a JSON object

Tags: node.js, qliksense

I am trying to serialize a Qlik Sense app (.qvf file) into a JSON object.
For that I am passing the .qvf file in the below code as directed here - https://github.com/mindspank/serializeapp

The main reason behind this exercise is to save the JSON in Gitlab for version control since we cannot save .qvf in Git for version control as it is a binary file.

```
var qsocks = require('qsocks')
var serializeapp = require('serializeapp')

qsocks.Connect()
.then(global => global.openDoc('Executive D:\Users\ddas7071\Documents\Qlik\Sense\Apps\NewDeb.qvf'))
.then(app => serializeapp(app))
.then(result => console.log(result))
serializeapp = require('serializeapp')
const enigma = require('enigma.js')
const WebSocket = require('ws')

enigma.getService('qix', {
schema: require(`./node_modules/enigma.js/schemas/qix/12.67.2.json`),
session: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 4848,
    secure: false
},
createSocket: (url) => new WebSocket(url)
})
  .then(qix => qix.global.openDoc('Executive 
D:\Users\ddas7071\Documents\Qlik\Sense\Apps\NewDeb.qvf'))
   .then(app => serializeapp(app))
   .then(result => console.log(result))
```

But while running the code (in windows), I am running into the below problem -

D:\Users\ddas7071\Desktop\Novartis_TechnicalDetails\myfile.js:12
enigma.getAttribute('qix', {
       ^

TypeError: enigma.getAttribute is not a function
    at Object. (D:\Users\ddas7071\Desktop\Novartis_TechnicalDetails\myfile.js:12:8)
[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)[39m
[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)[39m
[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)[39m
[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)[39m
[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47[39m

Though I understand the error, but not sure how to resolve it.
Note - All the pre-requisites are being taken care of already.

Answer (score 0):

`qsocks` is not supported from some time and `serializeapp` is using `qsocks` under the hood.

If you want to connect to Qlik Engine please the official package - [enigma.js](https://github.com/qlik-oss/enigma.js/). But there is no JS package (as far as i know that can extract the objects information.

But ...

There is a CLI (official) that can do this for you (havent tested it myself) - [corectl](https://github.com/qlik-oss/corectl). `Corectl` have option to [unbuild](https://github.com/qlik-oss/corectl/blob/master/docs/corectl_unbuild.md) the app into separate json/yaml files which you can then put under version control

The description for the `unbuild` command

> Extracts generic objects, dimensions, measures, variables, reload script and connections from an app in an engine into separate json and yaml files. In addition to the resources from the app a corectl.yml configuration file is generated that binds them all together. Passwords in the connection definitions can not be exported from the app and hence need to be handled manually. Generic Object trees (e.g. Qlik Sense sheets) are exported as a full property tree which means that child objects are found inside the parent´s json (the qChildren array).

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I have removed qsocks. The main issue I guess was, I was not running the engine-api-explorer (in dev-hub). Now I am trying to Deserialize it (from JSON back to .qvf) by following https://github.com/mindspank/buildapp but no luck yet. Any idea/suggestion on that?